Causality for gauge dependent operators in quantum field theories
Suppose that $\mathcal{A}_{ij...}(x)$ and $\mathcal{B}_{ij...}( x')$ are two gauge dependent (so non-observable) operator in some theory. If they are spacelike, should I impose the causality constraint for them?
\begin{equation}
[\mathcal{A}_{ij...}(x),\mathcal{B}_{kl...}( x')]=0,~~\text{if}~~ (x-x')^2>0.
\end{equation}
I think the above relation should be restricted to observable operators.

Correct. As an example of how causality cannot be imposed on the electromagnetic potentials, consider the Coulomb gauge. In this gauge the propagation is instantaneous.
